# Paytm Integration into Android App:SampleMerchantApp

Tags: android

This is with respect to the SampleMerchantApp that comes along with the paytm integration kit. I ran 'make project' to build the app and then I ran the app on my mobile, to see how the app works. But it gives 'Transaction failed' error. The app doesn't show a successful transaction. Could anyone help in this regard?

Comment: have you followed every step, including checksum generator and callbacks for success and failure from server side.

Comment: Yes, the sample app already includes checksum generation and checksum verification urls,and all the required callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check all the params

```
paramMap.put("REQUEST_TYPE", "DEFAULT");
 paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", ‘ORDER12345’)
 paramMap.put("MID", "klbGlV59135347348753");
 paramMap.put("CUST_ID”,’CUST110’)
 paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
```

etc....

So while I was implementing paytm in my application it always override Transaction failed, because checksum verification URL was not working. I fixed it, still it wasn't working because I was passing "WAP" instead of "WEB" or something. So kindly check one again all the parameters which you are passing with the request is proper, because with out debugging its hard to answer where the issue is arising as this paytm integration code is easily to use